# Is BootP still used?

Tags: networking, dhcp, bootp

I work in a relatively small company that develops and produces switches/routers. Our devices support BootP and DHCP servers/clients. We have a few bugs in the BootP and I'm thinking about suggesting the complete removal of this feature.

I've been dealing with other companies for 10 years now and I've never met a customer that deploys BootP on their devices. Only DHCP.
So I think it's not worth the effort to fix BootP and just simply remove this non-used feature.

***Question: Is BootP still being used out there? Didn't the DHCP replace it (completely) already?***

Comment: My 0.1% contribution; I've also never met bootp, in numerous years and companies I've worked for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: I would base my suggestions on more concrete data than a couple of experiences from an internet site. For example, customer survey with your clients.

Comment: I agree with Tero, that's why I don't think it's apropriate to post it as an answer. It's just my 0.1% contribution :) Yet it would be nice if other professionals also would testify their experience on this; I can't tell why you've got only my view. Thank you for suggesting though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The answer to this question is “absolutely”.

I work in a large (global, >$5Billion revenue) enterprise that has numerous BOOTP-only devices which give me monthly headaches.

I'm actively pushing our users to move to DHCP where at all possible. But there are many instruments and other networked devices that manufacturers have simply never bothered to update. DHCP supposes to support "BOOTP IP" assignments (though without the useful data such as lease times).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was very good to know.